# What is proper replacement for initContainer/job which runs once per deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I need a job to be run once every time I apply my configuration to Kubernetes. I tried to use a job but it does not allow to update image version and requires deletion of previous job. I tried to use initContainer but it seems to be overkill since I don't need this to be run every time pod is started.
Essentially I have simple deployment with single pod and need to run a job before deployment is happening every time I update image in deployment and confused what is the best way to achieve it. Job seems to be perfect for this but issue is that I can not submit the same config second time with update image tag for job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no other option. I recently had a similar situation and this is how I'm doing the job recreation:

```
kubectl get <job name> -o json | \
jq -r '.metadata.annotations."kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"' | \
kubectl replace --save-config --force -f -
```

It uses the `"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"` annotation, that holds the initial job config that was applied, without the auto-generated/cluster fields. Then the `kubectl replace` will completely replace the current one with a copy of itself, simulating the "rerun" that you are looking for.

You can then add to the snippet above some code replacing the image name/tag, before the `kubectl replace`.

Comment: Would not it be just simpler then delete job and apply config again it again (kubectl delete & kubectl apply)?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian it's another possibility, but this assumes that you have access to the kubectl config file, which depending in the situation may be impossible. That's why I gave this solution that works in all situations.